# str_replace seems to be disabling PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I am using str_replace to change the URLs in my template depending on the domain name selected. But it seems to be stopping the PHP code in the template from loading.

Here is what I have done:

```
<?php

$domain = $website_data['domain'];
$path_to_file = 'assets/sites/'.$domain.'/index.php';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace('domainhere',$domain,$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);

echo $file_contents;

?>
```

So it does what I want it to do, then it echos the $file_contents and the page displays file. Except any PHP stuff on the page just doesn't render.

For example if I do this:

```
<?php echo $domain ?>
```

It will just be blank, if I look at the source code I can see it written there as above.

I am not a PHP expert as you can guess so any ideas would be appreciated as I am obviously missing something!

Comment: php isn't recursively executable. echo doesn't EXECUTE anything, it just spits out whatever you tell it to. if that something contains `<?php ...?>` code blocks, well, that's just a `<` character, followed by a `?`, and a `p`, etc... if you want the code executed, then you'd need nasty hacks like `eval()`.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that "$domain" contains exactly what you expect?

Comment: @MarcB or just include / require? :-) which is basically the same as eval

Comment: *"For example if I do this:

<?php echo $domain ?>"* - do this where, from another file?

Comment: @PeeHaa: true 'nuff. missed the file_put_contents, so yeah, you could just `include` the outputted file.

Comment: Are you sure that the file you output/include does not have a tag opened at the end, preventing your echoed text from being rendered in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
<?php

$domain = $website_data['domain'];
$path_to_file = 'assets/sites/'.$domain.'/index.php';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace('domainhere',$domain,$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
include($path_to_file);

?>
```

As stated in the comments above, stuff displayed using `echo()` is not executed as program code.

Comment: @MikeA You're searching for 'domainhere' and replacing it. This is a permanent change, since you're writing it back to the file. The next time you search for it, it will not be there.

Comment: that is fine, its just generating a webpage, I only need it to run once. It's stop save me doing a manual "find and replace" in the text editor offline.

Comment: how is writing a 7 line php script, uploading it and executing it faster than pressing ctrl+f in a text editor?

Comment: because I have hundreds of files, this was just one example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suprised no one's mentioned what a freaking awful idea this is. If you have two different users accessing this script they are going to overwrite each other's changes. Besides, after the first change, the 'domainhere' will no longer exist in the original file.

Instead, anywhere you have "domainhere" in the first file, change it to a variable name, then set the variable before simply including the file.

Comment: I can't set "domainhere" as a variable as I am using some software that won't let me use <?php ?> tags, the software creates a webpage but it turns these tags into &lt; and &gt;